# How to organize better the taxonomy-selection drop-down box in Views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I made a View to list a series of items. Each item has been assigned a Taxonomy term.

My taxonomy terms go like this:

```
--- Main1
----- Sub1
----- Sub2
--- Main2
----- Sub3
----- Sub4
----- Sub5
```

So there's a main category and inside other terms.

In my view, you can filter the entries to only display items for a certain category. **But the dropdown menu is a mess**. It goes like Sub3, Main2, Sub1, Sub5...

So, is there a way to organize it in a way it appears as I listed it above? And also, is it possible to give some kind of indentation for the  subterms in the dropdown? (So people can easily tell what is a main term and what's a sub-term).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module to manage taxonomy terms in select list.

See this discussion to implement hierarchical select with Views module : http://drupal.org/node/1170192

Answer (score 0):

Check also [Better exposed filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) - it allows you to display the filter in checkboxes/radios instead of dropdowns (which are horrible for end users) and then you can further style the output to group and divide main categories visually.

Here's a screenshot of something similar I did:

[image]

Comment: The "further style" is a feature of that module or did you mean I should edit the code?

Comment: I did not edit the code if that's what you are asking, I just styled it the way I needed it to be.

Comment: Checkboxes are cool, but I fear I have dozens of terms,  so the list gets too large.